# What do you do when your application starts to run out of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, windows-7

I have a C++ graphics app that does heavy computations on models.  There is a [leak or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459040/does-cg-3-0-leak) which I've traced to CG and/or my ATI graphics card (I'm 100% SURE!!).  The machine I have has 16 GB ram, and when I've used 4.49 GB RAM (TOTAL system usage, with app only using ~1.9GB), vector.resize() starts returning 0 new elements and not being able to resize an array.  Why so soon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Windows Assumed)

A 32-bit Windows application is limited to about 2.0 GB of user-mode memory (or 3.0 GB if certain boot-time parameters are set).  When your application used up 1.9 GB of memory, the well ran dry.

Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits

Comment: Ok! In VS 2010 [Project Properties/Config/Linker/System: Enable Large Addresses=YES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: That's only half of it.  You also have to have Windows boot in such a way so that 3GB is reserved for user space, rather than the usual 2 GB.  The method for doing this differs with your specific version of Windows.

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2006/10/03/hey-where-did-_2f00_3gb-go-in-longhorn-and-vista_3f00_.aspx

Comment: INTERESTING. That's why I saw [this](http://i.imgur.com/LdMsJ.png) on first launch+crash (and after it changed "compatibility settings", it ran successfully (and is consuming 5.5GB as we speak!))

Answer (score 1):

I changed the build configuration to x64 and the application works fine

Comment: didn't you know ,32bit programs can only address 2GB of RAM ?

Comment: Actually assumed it was 2^32=4GB!

Answer (score 0):

**Throw an exception!**
Best to find and stamp on the leak, of course, but when you run out of memory: exception! To be extra cool restart your own application in response.

Comment: This requires wrapping EVERY `.resize()` with a check that `.size()`== size_you_wanted, and every `malloc()` and `new` must be checked to see if NULL was returned.